# Why I can't use this as a model on my index page?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core

I have a class named Banner which I want to use as a model for my index page. But whenever I try to use it, I receive the following errors:

"The name Banner does not exist in current context"

"The name of type or namespace Banner cannot be found ( Missing directive or reference )"

I've always used models like this and for other classes it works fine...

After some seach I found some answers but none worked, this is what I've tried:

- Restarting the computer
- Restarting Visual Studio
- Deleting .vs folder
- Recreating Banner class

---

Index.cshtml

```
@model QBit_Ecommerce_Mvc.Models.Util.Banner

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}


<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/Index.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                @{ int cont = 0;}
                @foreach (Banner _Banner in Banner.listaBanners)
                {
                    if (cont == 0)
                    {
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@_Banner._Imagem" alt="First slide" height="400">
                        </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@_Banner._Imagem" alt="Second slide" height="400">
                        </div>
                    }
                    cont++;
                }                
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is where the Banner is not recognized:

```
@foreach (Banner _Banner in Banner.listaBanners)
```

And here is my Banner class:

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QBit_Ecommerce_Mvc.Models.Util
{
    public class Banner : Conexao
    {
        #region "Construtores"
        public Banner()
        {

        }
        #endregion

        #region "Propriedades"
        public string _Imagem { get; set; }
        public byte[] _ImagemBytes { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region "Variáveis"
        public static List<Banner> listaBanners = new List<Banner>();
        #endregion

        #region "Métodos"
        public List<Banner> GetBanners()
        {
            try
            {
                string sql = "SELECT Imagem FROM EcommerceBanners";
                DataTable dtBanner = new DataTable();

                using (SqlConnection _Connection = Conectar())
                {
                    using (SqlCommand _Command = new SqlCommand(sql, _Connection))
                    {
                        _Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        SqlDataReader reader;
                        using (reader = _Command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            dtBanner.Load(reader);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (dtBanner.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow _RowBanner in dtBanner.Rows)
                    {
                        Banner _Banner = new Banner();
                        _Banner._ImagemBytes = (byte[])_RowBanner.ItemArray[0];
                        _Banner._Imagem = Convert.ToBase64String(_Banner._ImagemBytes);
                        listaBanners.Add(_Banner);
                    }
                }
                return listaBanners;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

---

**Any ideas on how to fix this and use my model on index?**

---

**EDIT**

Controller index action

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            if(Produto.listaProdutos.Count() <= 0)
            {
                Produto _Produto = new Produto();
                _Produto.CarregaListaProdutos();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Where is your index action?

Comment: I tested your scenario, but it worked for me. I just comment the query section to avoid error, so set the Banner list manually, and it worked like a charm. I think you would better set an item into your Banner object and comment the query part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is where the Banner is not recognized:
>
> @foreach (Banner _Banner in Banner.listaBanners)

Since you want to use Banner class in the View page(.cshtml), you have to add the namespace first. So, try to add `@using QBit_Ecommerce_Mvc.Models.Util` at the head of the page.

In the Index.cshtml, code like below:

```
@using QBit_Ecommerce_Mvc.Models.Util
@model QBit_Ecommerce_Mvc.Models.Util.Banner
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}


<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/Index.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                @{ int cont = 0;}
                @foreach (Banner _Banner in Banner.listaBanners)
                {
                    if (cont == 0)
                    {
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@_Banner._Imagem" alt="First slide" height="400">
                        </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@_Banner._Imagem" alt="Second slide" height="400">
                        </div>
                    }
                    cont++;
                }                
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tested this and it works. Adding this line @using QBit_Ecommerce_Mvc.Models.Util was the fix.